# JPA error from GAE data store

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to have my GAE app pull some records from the Datastore but keep getting this:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Class PersistableItem for query has not been resolved. Check the query and any imports specification
```

It's from the method here:

```
public List<PersistableItem> listItems() {
    EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
    // Read the existing entries
    Query q = em.createQuery("select * from PersistableItem");
    List<PersistableItem> items = q.getResultList();
    return items; 
}
```

From what I've read this is about importing my PersistableItem class but I'm confused as I already do that in the .java code files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is strange, so this might not be your only error, but your query is wrong. select * is SQL, not JPQL. The correct query is

```
select p from PersistableItem p
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the class "PersistableItem" present in your project (or in a dependency of your project). Does it have the `@Entity` class level annotation. Does it implement Serializable. In your JPQL try using the fully qualified name of the class ("select * from package1.package2.PersistableItem")

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error even with the right JPQL query and solved adding the class declarations in the persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="appengine-transactions-optional">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>it.gustaff.data.Place</class>
    <class>it.gustaff.data.Menu</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```